# using php variables on .htaccess for url rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a php file lets say `test.php?x=1` with .htaccess i can rewrite the url.

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^some-page_([0-9]+)_(.+)?$ test.php?x=$1 [L]
```

Normally i can write whatever i want write after x on the url.
Now here is the thing that i want to make;
In the test.php file there is a variable `$name`. 
I want to write that variable into .htaccess thus i would like to make make link below

`localhost/some-page_1_SOME-TEXT-COMING-FROM-VARIABLE`

How could i do that? Thank you.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: to make friendly urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^some-page_([0-9]+)_(.+)?$ test.php?x=$1&name=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^some-page_([0-9]+)?$ test.php?x=$1 [L]
```

That second line with allow you to just have localhost/some-page_1 work as well.

The above will, or should, rewrite the first line below into the bottom URL:

```
localhost/some-page_1_SOME-TEXT-COMING-FROM-VARIABLE
localhost/some-page.php?id=1&name=SOME-TEXT-COMING-FROM-VARIABLE
```

Comment: `$name` is a varible has a value fetched from mysql. I need to write `$name``s value after `$_GET['x']` on .htaccess.
Let me tell what i want;
`RewriteRule ^some-page_([0-9]+)?$ test.php?x=$1_$name [L]`

Comment: on test.php `$name=test` i want to make my url `/some-page_34_test`

Comment: i have done it thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Apache rewrite rules and PHP have nothing to do with each other.

Rewrite rules also don't "make links". They simply control which script or program is executed in response to URLs.